# Explanation for micros function

Tags: programming

I was trying to understand the working of micros() function internally and I had a look at the function in Arduino.h

This is the code:

```
unsigned long micros() {
    unsigned long m;
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG, t;

    cli();
    m = timer0_overflow_count;
 #if defined(TCNT0)
    t = TCNT0;
 #elif defined(TCNT0L)
    t = TCNT0L;
#else
    #error TIMER 0 not defined
#endif


#ifdef TIFR0
        if ((TIFR0 & _BV(TOV0)) && (t & 255))
        m++;
#else
        if ((TIFR & _BV(TOV0)) && (t & 255))
        m++;
#endif

    SREG = oldSREG;

    return ((m << 8) + t) * (64 / clockCyclesPerMicrosecond());
}
```

Can someone please explain me what this line is doing :

```
  if ((TIFR0 & _BV(TOV0)) && (t & 255))
   m++;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the timer 0 has overflowed (`TIFR0 & _BV(TOV0)`) and there is at least a count of 1 in the timer count register (`t & 255`) then increment the local copy of the overflow count.

That overflow count is used later on to add an upper 8 bits to what is basically an 8 bit counter to turn it into a 16 bit one (`(m << 8) + t`).

Comment: can you please explain me "timer0_overflow_count" too?

Comment: It's the current count of timer overflows - it's incremented in an interrupt routine elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Since at the start of this function interrupts have been disabled by the `cli()` function it is possible that the timer `TCNT0` has overflowed yet this *event* has not been processed and included in the value of `timer0_overflow_count` that has been read into `m`. Therefore the line that you are asking about is checking for this condition and incrementing the local copy `m` if necessary before using it to calculate the number of microseconds since startup.